# Automated installation of the operating system via ipmi using some solution

Tags: linux, ansible, openstack, bare-metal-server

Suggest a solution if such exists.
There are 20 empty baremetal servers. Me need to go to the ipmi and manually connect the image file to start the installation OS.
Question: are there any solutions to automate this process?

Answer (score 1):

Since you tag this question with "OpenStack", you must have heard of Ironic.

If the thought of installing OpenStack to automatically install servers frightens you, look up Cobbler. It was used by now defunct products Helion OpenStack and SUSE OpenStack Cloud to set up clouds.

Ubuntu uses MAAS for this purpose.

This is not a complete list.